# Alter string using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a XML file loaded into a String like this

```
<children name="{content.type}">
    <values>{video}</values>
</children>
<children name="{content.size}">
    <values>250</values>
</children>
<children name="uploaded by">
    <values>user1</values>
</children>
```

I want to remove the {} in the name tags so the output looks like this

```
<children name="content.type">
    <values>{video}</values>
</children>
<children name="content.size">
    <values>250</values>
</children>
<children name="uploaded by">
    <values>user1</values>
</children>
```

Currently I have this code -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^,]*)\"\\{([^,]*)\\}\"([^,]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

But the string gets cutoff midway. Is something wrong with my regex?

Comment: Don't you need to concatenate the second and third group? You are printing only the first captured group right now I think.

Comment: Haha I feel like an idiot. Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
content.replaceAll("\\bname=\"\\{([^}]+)\\}\"", "name=\"$1\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this work ?

```
s.replaceAll( "name=\"\\{", "name=\"" ).replaceAll( "\\}\">", "\">" )
```

Comment: This will work only if OP wont have other attributes in his input like `<children name="{content.type}" someOtherAttrib="{some.value}">`